# Grabbing data based on column headers properly in Python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, dataformat

I am trying to grab data from a url. My snippet is working  but I need more ideas to improve this. In the page that I am trying to grab, there are 7 column headers but some rows have only 5 data. Is there a better way of grabbing the data from columns ( Parent Txn Hash, Type, From, Tom Value )?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, random, ctypes
import requests, os
from time import sleep
from time import strftime

user_agent_list = [
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36'}"
]
header = random.choice(user_agent_list)
trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')


url = "https://bscscan.com/txsInternal?a=0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c&ps=100&p=1"

reqblockdetails = requests.get(url,header, timeout=10)
soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(reqblockdetails.content, 'html.parser')
rowsblockdetails = soupblockdetails.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr', limit=100)
for row in rowsblockdetails[1:]:
    rowr = row.find_all('td')[0].text[0:]
    if rowr != "":
        ptxnhash = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]  #-- is on [3]
        ptxnhash = str(ptxnhash).strip()
        exectype1 = row.find_all('td')[4].text[0:]
        source1 = row.find_all('td')[5].text[0:]
        destination1 = row.find_all('td')[7].text[0:]
        amount1 = row.find_all('td')[8].text[0:]
        amount1 = trim.sub('', amount1)
        rptblockdetails = str("%s" % ptxnhash + "\t%s" % source1 + " \t%s" % destination1 + " \t%s" % amount1)
        print (rptblockdetails)
        
    ptxnhash = row.find_all('td')[2].text[0:]  #-- while here is on [2]
    ptxnhash = str(ptxnhash).strip()
    if ptxnhash.startswith ('0x'):
        txnhashdetails = ptxnhash.strip()
        exectype = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
        source = row.find_all('td')[4].text[0:]
        source = source.strip()
        destination = row.find_all('td')[6].text[0:]
        destination = str(destination).replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
        destination = destination.strip()
        amount = row.find_all('td')[7].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', amount)       
        rptblockdetails = str("%s" % ptxnhash + " \t%s" % source  + " \t%s" % destination + " \t%s" % amount)
        print (rptblockdetails)
```

Current Output:

```
0xf864a52f67b55252bac44ff5a4187cae9c3044245ddc3e094286d1dc5876175f  Binance: WBNB Token     PancakeSwap: Router v2  0.123538253669756
0x7be9b2e0ea4c88853e91d2534aeb9542f9234313cc305085e6c808c806a87cbf  Binance: WBNB Token     PancakeSwap: Router v2  0.091183472723697
0x7be9b2e0ea4c88853e91d2534aeb9542f9234313cc305085e6c808c806a87cbf  Binance: WBNB Token     PancakeSwap: Router v2  0.027077169875612
0x02ab699bc69f09ee1ab315259260a8e9baa84bc1f72e9d285426f8be5c7e1c9a  Binance: WBNB Token     PancakeSwap: Router v2  0.560826883730127
0xe3fd62ca86f93a780fb63eb17356e28d4dc1d8d5431736750b9a03c181bd449a  Binance: WBNB Token     PancakeSwap: Router v2  0.031760167285687
```

Comment: can show share it? It will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will get all data from the page and create pandas DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bscscan.com/txsInternal?a=0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c&ps=100&p=1"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    if len(tds) == 9:
        tds.pop(6)
        tds.pop(1)
    else:
        block = row.find_previous(
            lambda tag: tag.name == "td"
            and "bg-soft-secondary" in tag.attrs.get("class", [])
            and tag.find("a")
        )
        tds[0] = block.get_text(strip=True)
        tds[1] = block.find_next("td").find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
        tds.pop(5)

    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data,
    columns=["Block", "Age", "Parent Txn Hash", "Type", "From", "To", "Value"],
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
      Block          Age                                                     Parent Txn Hash  Type                                        From                                          To                   Value
0   9655148  39 secs ago  0xe4757e4012ac1e5a2560174f9db3d74dd85fcda5c513b251301ef2239a7b0da1  call                         Binance: WBNB Token  0xcf0febd3f17cef5b47b0cd257acf6025c5bff3b7   0.032619188744045 BNB
1   9655148  39 secs ago  0xdaba21a2133a1c9244271f6ace04484d89bb69bf0fc0cebea9da83facf7c9156  call                                Mdex: Router                         Binance: WBNB Token                 0.5 BNB
2   9655148  39 secs ago  0x623f5eb7ee7452f2deebc5d228e6d426f7283773455905ae933cc5a3f294a8bb  call                         Binance: WBNB Token                      PancakeSwap: Router v2                0.78 BNB
3   9655148  39 secs ago  0x5e5bed183342a82ce1ab1d978d4b9a4059b0a7903736c6ea33ca332034c2fcc1  call                         Binance: WBNB Token                      PancakeSwap: Router v2   0.014049013918158 BNB
4   9655148  39 secs ago  0x407f274d8a45f5cf1bca80b4dcc1c3ab2c70f3281ebc77276d617b84aef257a2  call                      PancakeSwap: Router v2                         Binance: WBNB Token               0.395 BNB
5   9655148  39 secs ago  0xa6172d1aad2938d7640cef2b4189bc85c17f89ca621917fb06c351bc1ef3d9c4  call                         Binance: WBNB Token                      PancakeSwap: Router v2   0.661559048339038 BNB

...
```

and creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]